# self.viewDelegate = 0x0 why?

Tags: iphone, uiview, touchesbegan

In the following code the
`self.viewDelegate` is `0x0` and I don't know how to solve
this problem. Should I have to go to the interface Builder?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        if ([self.viewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(openFlowView:doubleTapOnIndex:itemView:)])
            [self.viewDelegate openFlowView:self doubleTapOnIndex:selectedCoverView.number itemView:selectedCoverView];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewDelegate is not defined.
Usually, in Apple class, view delegate is just call delegate. You should have taken this code from somewhere.
You have to defined viewDelegate in your code (not IB)

```
self.viewDelegate=xxxx;
```

xxxx must be your delegate. Delegate could be self !

See [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) for delegate explanation

Comment: Yes but how can i define viewDelegate in  my code, could you please help me o don't have a solution?

Comment: i have found this line in the code                                      @property (nonatomic, assign) id <AFOpenFlowViewDelegate> viewDelegate; yes but which what thing i have to define it?

Comment: please don't be angry but i don't know what you mean with self.viewDelegate = xxxxx; because i am very new in objective-C in which method i have to define this? and what do you mean with "delegate could be self"?

Comment: I don't want to be angry, but before using code you get on the net, you should understand it.

Comment: Yes i understand a lot of objective-C i have a good book, but this problem is with an ready code from the internet (AFOpenFlow) and my App is going to be ready when i solved this problem, i work on this problem for 2 weeks now and i don't have a solution so i hope for help from you :) because i don't know in which method of this class i have to define self.viewDelegate and what i have to set on xxxxx?

Comment: replace xxxx by your delegate

Comment: The delegate must have the method openFlowView:doubleTapOnIndex:itemView:

Comment: ahhhh okay so AFOpenFlowView.m is my delegate?

Comment: AFOpenFlowView.m is a file name. It should define AFOpenFlowView class. Then your delegate must be an instance of this class (that should be a view).

Comment: The problem is the class is not from me, it is a class from the internet and i don't know what is the delegate there, you say delegate is like (AFOpenFlowView *) testView?